# Does Windows Phone provide a better interface to ID3 tags?

Tags: 8.0, apps, music

I am a freak who likes to keep things organized.

I have spent past year collecting accurate information for my song collection (i.e. info on Singer, Contributing Artists, Album, Year, Songwriter, composer etc.) & editing this info (in id3 tags) on my PC using Mediamonkey.

Now I want my cellphone to accurately use this info.

I am currently using Android. But Android does not provide a good interface to id3 tags (or so I have read on various android forums).

E.g.

> If a song has multiple contributing artists, then this info is entered as following: singer 1 **;** singer 2.
>
> In android, instead of displaying these two artists separately in the Artist's list (in any Music Player) a single artist is shown with a single name: Singer 1 **/** Singer2.

This was just an example. There are many other things that show the poor interface to and poorer use of id3 tags.

I want to know if Windows Phone provides a better integration by default, if not, then does it has an app that does so?

Comment: So you want to know if the built-in music player supports ID3 tags properly?

Comment: @NeilTurner: In a way, yes. But according to my understanding, the OS provides this interface and I am not sure if an app can handle this data on its own. However it that is possible, is there an app that can handle data properly.